# Ubuntu 23.10 Boot Problems

Tags: boot, grub2, russian

I have a long-standing problem that prevents me from using Ubuntu. Ubuntu, after a proper and stable installation with USB, refuses to boot, does not even come out any logo, not even a boot menu. A black screen just appears with a flashing underline [dash] in the corner. I'd also like to note that this problem applies to ubuntu-based distributions. The only exceptions are distributions with major modifications [e.g. Trisquel].

Sorry if I didn't provide enough information. I will answer any question if it is necessary for the solution. Thank you in advance, caring people.

Comment: In english please.

Comment: I put your question in English using translate.bing.com . Please do the same to continue receiving support.  Я задал ваш вопрос на английском языке с помощью translate.bing.com . Пожалуйста, сделайте то же самое, чтобы продолжить получать поддержку.

Comment: Please tell us on what laptop or desktop computer you are trying to install Ubuntu. Write the answer in your question. Give as much information as possible.